# Which stats model to predict rank when participants arrange conditions by rank?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, ranking

**Just a quick clarification:** This question is about when *participants* specify which condition is most X, second most X, third most X, etc. It's not about the researcher converting continuous DV's into ranks in order to run a particular test.

I have data from a study where participants played a game under three conditions (C1, C2, and C3), and ranked each condition in order of least to most fun. Ties were allowed, in which case the resulting ranks were averaged. Thus, a condition could be ranked 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, or 3. I also have some information about the participants, such as whether or not they like playing games in general.

I would like to model the data such that I can predict the rank (DV) depending the condition (first IV), whether or not the participant likes games in general (second IV), and any interaction effects between these.

I've considered using (and am fairly familiar with) ordered logit or probit, linear, generalized linear, or a mixed effects model. The reason I'm confused is that the data is definitely repeated measures, but not in the sense that I want to analyze variation within each participant (as in a mixed model). That wouldn't make sense because every participants' mean rank is always 2. Instead, a given rank is largely dependent on that participant's other two ranks. For example, a participant can't rank two conditions #1--in that case they would tie and would both be #1.5, with the other condition necessarily being #3.

In case it's relevant, I'm using R.

Comment: I think "multinomial logit" and "rank ordered logit" models are used in discrete choice problems like this

Comment: Don't the ties kind of mess-up the possibility of using one of these categorical-response models? Or do you want to think of the response having 5 levels 1, 1.5, ..., 3?

Comment: Yes, currently I'm interpreting it as five levels. I am looking into rank ordered logit models right now, and it looks promising although I feel like my head is going to explode particularly with regard to the ties.